# The method for pushing to a new view controller in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've made a carousel with buttons on it, which should lead to other view controllers.

However, I can't ctrl+drag the buttons onto the new view controllers to push them because the carousel view isn't in the beginning view controller.

Some images are added in the drive link below:
[Pictures](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B66972SsSRztWmotV01JN0JSdHc/view?usp=sharing)

This is the code which adds 2 buttons to the carousel and the carousel func itself:

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)) //Adding the buttons

    if index == 0 {
        let actua = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        actua.setTitle("Actua", forState: .Normal)
        actua.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)

        let HeistLeeftFoto = UIImage.init(named: "HeistLeeft")
        actua.setBackgroundImage(HeistLeeftFoto!, forState: .Normal)
        tempView.addSubview(actua)
    }

    else if index == 1 {
        let shoppen = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        shoppen.setTitle("Shoppen", forState: .Normal)
        shoppen.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

        let BergStraatFoto = UIImage.init(named: "Bergstraat")
        shoppen.setBackgroundImage(BergStraatFoto!, forState: .Normal)
        tempView.addSubview(shoppen)
    }
```

In an earlier question, someone told me to add the following action:

```
actua.addTarget(self, action: ViewController.pushActua, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And he advised me to then write a method to push it to the ViewControllerActua view. Does anyone have an idea how to write this method or how to do this another way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create segues that link your view controller object to your other scenes and then you can invoke these segues programmatically by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from the iCaoursel delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndex`

Comment: So I made an segue from my initial view controller and the next one, and called it SegueActua (identifier), and then added the line `actua.addTarget(self, action: performSegueWithIdentifier(SegueActua, sender: self), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

This gives me a warning, "use of unresolved identifier "SegueActua"", any ideas? :)

Comment: No, you can't use button action events.  Your should simply put `UIImageViews` in your carousel rather than `UIButtons` and then implement the iCarousel delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndex` - The index supplied to this method will be your button number, 0 or 1.  You can then call `performSegueWithIdentifier` using the appropriate segue identifier

Comment: Why are you using carousel if you only have two items?  If you plan on having more and some items will go off screen then you will have a problem using buttons

Comment: Yes, there are more ;) I just didn't see the use of showing you all the code, since it's all more or less the same (still have to fix the repeating code, but i'm a beginner at swift coding, which you probably noticed already :p)

Comment: Ohh okay, thanks! I think i should manage now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also created this type of view and pushing I have used the following code.

Here is the method

```
func pushRegisterView()
{
    let viewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as? ViewController // To which you want to go
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerObj!, animated: true)
}
```

Here is the code for adding to button

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAtIndex index: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
let tempView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)) //Adding the buttons

if index == 0 {
    let actua = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

    actua.setTitle("Actua", forState: .Normal)
    actua.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    actua.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pushRegisterView),
                                 forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    let HeistLeeftFoto = UIImage.init(named: "HeistLeeft")
    actua.setBackgroundImage(HeistLeeftFoto!, forState: .Normal)
    tempView.addSubview(actua)



}

else if index == 1 {
    let shoppen = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

    shoppen.setTitle("Shoppen", forState: .Normal)
    shoppen.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    shoppen.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pushRegisterView),
                                 forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    let BergStraatFoto = UIImage.init(named: "Bergstraat")
    shoppen.setBackgroundImage(BergStraatFoto!, forState: .Normal)
    tempView.addSubview(shoppen)
}
```

Here is the code for flip animation and pop if you want

```
    // Method used for flipping the view
func flipanimationblock ()
{
    let screen = TypeTwoNib.instanceFromNib()
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.carousel.itemViewAtIndex(index)!, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations:
        { () -> Void in
            screen.bttn_First.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.popbackToIntialViewController),
                forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            screen.bttn_First.setTitle("OK!", forState: .Normal)
            self.items.replaceObjectAtIndex(self.index, withObject: screen)

    }) { (Bool) in
        print(screen.frame)
        self.carousel.reloadItemAtIndex(self.index, animated: true)

    }
 }

    func popbackToIntialViewController()
{
    let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I still have a problem though.. When I add it like so (i changed the "StoryboardID" to "ViewControllerActua", a viewcontroller i have, just to check if it works, it gives me the warning: "use of unresolved identifier 'viewRegister'". Any ideas on how to fix this? :)

Comment: func pushRegisterView()
{
    let viewControllerObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardID") as? ViewController // To which you want to go
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerObj!, animated: true)
}

Comment: I thought for a moment it was about to work, but then I realized i hadn't added a navigation controller yet. So i embedded my carousel view controller in in it. It still doesn't work though.. I added pictures of the error i'm getting now in this drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66972SsSRztZzJaNGcyS3VLX28)  . First i got a SIGABRT error as well, but i fixed that quite easily by changing the StoryboardID to ViewControllerActua

Comment: i meant this link (previous one was faulty) [pictures](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B66972SsSRztbUlFb2xPN2ttSDQ&usp=sharing)

Comment: It works! i changed the function into: `func pushRegisterViewActua()
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueActua", sender: self)
    }`